# How to register ECS Service into a Target group defined in a another stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I have 2x stacks, the first defines my Application LB and the other defines my ECS service.

In the first stack, I have defined multiple target groups for my multiple ECS services and would like to register its corresponding service.

For reference, I followed this example [here to split my app up](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/cross-stack-load-balancer/split-at-targetgroup.ts)

How can I register my ECS service into a target group defined in another stack?

My ECS Service...

```js
    const service = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'jenkinsService', {
      cluster: props.cluster,
      taskDefinition,
      serviceName: 'Jenkins-Master',
      minHealthyPercent: 0,
      maxHealthyPercent: 100
    });

    props.targetGroup.addTarget(service) // I want to register against a specific Target Group
```

My custom target group

```js
        const jenkinsMastertargetGroup = this.targetGroup = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'Jenkins-Master', {
          vpc: props.vpc,
          port: 80,
          targetType: elbv2.TargetType.INSTANCE,
          targetGroupName: 'WDD-Jenkins-Master',
          deregistrationDelay: cdk.Duration.seconds(250),
          healthCheck:{
            port: '8080',
            path:'/log/all',
            interval: cdk.Duration.minutes(3)
          }

        });
```

The action on my listener to forward to the TG

```js
        elbHTTPlistener.addAction('JenkinsMasterResponse', {
          priority: 5,
          conditions: [
            //ListenerCondition.hostHeaders(['sub1.test.com.au/jenkins']),
            ListenerCondition.pathPatterns(['/jenkins']),
          ],
          action: ListenerAction.forward([jenkinsMastertargetGroup]),
        });
```

Comment: you are following the example provides from aws, you should be already able to pass your targetGroup object from one "stack" to another "stack". Unless your each "stack" is sitting on different deployment, like you have to run "cdk deploy" on each stack. I did similar thing on 2 different cdk deployments.

Comment: Could you share an example? @Chun

Answer (score 1):

I found a relatively simple solution to this problem, using imports/exports in cloudformation.

In the 1st stack where I defined my Application ELB, I define an empty target group and then export the ARN for the target group.

Make sure to add a rule for your TG.

```js
const emptytg = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'tg1', {
        vpc,
        port: 80,
        targetGroupName: 'name',
        targetType: elbv2.TargetType.INSTANCE,
});

Listener.addAction('tg1', {
        priority: 2,
        conditions:[
          ListenerCondition.pathPatterns(['/tg1']),
        ],
        action: ListenerAction.forward([tg1])
      });

new cdk.CfnOutput(this,'tg1Export', {
      value: emptytg.targetGroupArn,
      exportName: 'emptytgARN'
    });
```

Below is the other stack containing the ECS service, you can import the TG and then use the .addTarget target method.

```js
const importedGroup = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup.fromTargetGroupAttributes(this, 'imported-tg',{
targetGroupArn: cdk.Fn.importValue('wddSharedResourcesjenkinsMastertargetGrouptargetGroupArn'),
});

importedGroup.addTarget(service);
```

This works pretty well for me and I hope it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My use case is using 1 Application Load Balancer (and 1 Listener HTTPS) and has different paths that point to different ECS deployments

e.g.

- https://app.example.com/application-a/ to ECS deployment A
- https://app.example.com/application-b/ to ECS deployment B

And the way I config is different then yours. Rather than setting all the Target Group in the Listener stack, I define those target group on the ECS stack.

StackLoadBalancer

```js
    const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'LB', {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: true
    });

    // make sure allow Application Load Balancer can accessing out to reach private service
    lb.connections.securityGroups[0].addEgressRule(
      ec2.Peer.ipv4(vpc.vpcCidrBlock),
      ec2.Port.allTcp(),
      "Allow Local Balancer to access service");

    lb.logAccessLogs(logBucket)

    const defaultTargetGroup = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'TargetGroup', {
      vpc: vpc,
      port: 80
    });

    const listener = lb.addListener('Listener', {
      port: 443,
      certificates: [certification],
      defaultTargetGroups: [defaultTargetGroup],
      open: true
    });

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'listenerarn', { value: listener.listenerArn, exportName: this.stackName + "-listenerarn" })
```

StackA

```js
   const ecsService = new ecs.Ec2Service(this, 'Service', {
      cluster,
      taskDefinition
    });

    ecsService.connections.securityGroups[0].addIngressRule(
      ec2.Peer.ipv4(vpc.vpcCidrBlock),
      ec2.Port.allTcp(),
      "Allow CloudFormation ECS Service Update Properly"
    );

    const targetGroup = new elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(this, 'application-a-tg', {
      vpc,
      port: portNumber,
      protocol: elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
      healthCheck: {
        interval: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
        path: "/",
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(5),
        healthyHttpCodes: "200-499"
      },
      stickinessCookieDuration: cdk.Duration.hours(1),
      deregistrationDelay: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
      targets: [
        ecsService.loadBalancerTarget({
          containerName: 'web'
        })]
    });


    const rule1 = new elbv2.CfnListenerRule(this, "rule1", {
      listenerArn: cdk.Fn.importValue("StackLoadBalancerStack-listenerarn"),
      actions: [{
        type: "forward",
        targetGroupArn: targetGroup.targetGroupArn
      }],
      conditions: [{
        field: "path-pattern",
        pathPatternConfig: {
          values: ["/application-a/*"]
        },

      }],
      priority: 10
    });
```

The most important part in StackA is the CfnListenerRule, I was not able to fine a "native" CDK code to do this at the time I developed.

Comment: Hi @Chun thanks for the help I have updated with the solution that worked for me. My solution might help as it's more 'native' and uses less code.

Thanks again!